# Build Flutter Application for x86 and x86_64

Tags: android, flutter

I was trying to build flutter application, it was successfull, but i can't install it on ASUS T00G and x86 Android Emulator. And after finding out the release is only available for arm & arm64. Is there any possible way to do a Release Build to both x86 and arm?

Answer (score 1):

That's currently not supported.

There is an open issue that you can upvote https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: The linked issue is still open.

Answer (score 1):

The linked issue in above answer has been closed on 23 Oct

```
jonahwilliams commented on 23 Oct
On master, Flutter now supports the x86_64 (64 bit) Android ABI. The engine also has support for building in x86 (32 bit) by following instructions at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/JIT-Release-Modes
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253#issuecomment-545082953

You can find an android-x86-jit-release folder in bin/cache/artifacts/engine 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the steps how you build this release. And which programs to download and from where to build a jit release